# How to call redirect_to in redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, redmine

I'm using custom_workflow Redmine plugin and want to use Rails `redirect_to` function, but can't call it.
I have already tried to make a class like

```rb
class CustomRedirect < ApplicationController
    def redirect
        redirect_to (:controller => 'issues')
    end
end
```

but no chances.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly happens when you run this code? Do you get an exception? Any unexpected behavior? Please add some details to your question about (1) your desired behavior and (2) the actual behavior of your code.

Comment: @HolgerJust undefined method `redirect' for CustomRedirect Class

Comment: Have you tried to redirect directly from the `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @DmitriySkogorev Share your terminal logs. And also share your routes file

Comment: @DmitriySkogorev Sorry, but you provided not much info... How do you call the "redirect"-function and from where?